# How to set the default role for EJB methods in JBoss 7?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, jboss7.x

I have an EAR with multiple EJB JARs which shall be secured by using a very simple authentication mechanisms: Every EJB method shall be accessible by every user as long as he/she is authenticated. So I have secured the EAR file by adding the `security-domain` to the `jboss-app.xml` file into the EAR:

```
<jboss-app>
  <security-domain>my-security-domain</security-domain>
</jboss-app>
```

Users are authenticated with ths JBoss default `users.properties` file. In JBoss 4.2.3 this just worked fine. Now in JBoss 7 I get an authorization exception:

```
16:45:32,791 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MyServiceBean for method public abstract java.util.List mypackage.MyService.findAllFoo(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public abstract java.util.List mypackage.MyService.findAllFoo() of bean: MyServiceBean is not allowed
```

After setting the logger category for `org.jboss.security` to `TRACE` I found out, that JBoss 7 obviously expects a default `<NOBODY>` role on every EJB method, when no explicit role is specified otherwise. From the logs:

```
16:45:32,791 TRACE [org.jboss.security.audit] (EJB default - 2) [Failure]Source=org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper;Action=authorization;Exception:=PBOX000017: Acces denied: authorization failed ;Resource:=[org.jboss.security.authorization.resources.EJBResource:contextMap={policyRegistration=null}:method=public abstract java.util.List mypackage.MyService.findAllFoo():ejbMethodInterface=Remote:ejbName=MyServiceBean:ejbPrincipal=rschneider:MethodRoles=Roles(<NOBODY>,):securityRoleReferences=null:callerSubject=Betreff:
    Principal: org.jboss.remoting3.security.UserPrincipal@ce844325
    Principal: Roles(members:user)
    Principal: CallerPrincipal(members:org.jboss.remoting3.security.UserPrincipal@ce844325)
:callerRunAs=null:callerRunAs=null:ejbRestrictionEnforcement=false:ejbVersion=2.0];policyRegistration=null;
```

Then I tried to configure a role-mapping into JBoss, so that every user is mapped to this `<NOBODY>` role:

```
<security-domain name="my-security-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/rolesMapping-roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Content of the `rolesMapping-roles.properties` file:

```
user=user,<NOBODY>
```

This works, but I am very uneasy about this solution. So, is there a way to tell JBoss 7 to use a default role for every EJB method, e.g. `user`? I really do not want to annotate every bean with a `@RolesAllowed("user")`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really an answer to my specific question, but it solves the problem in a way better fashion.

After digging in the [JBoss AS/Wildfly source code](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly) and stumbling [upon a blog post](http://anil-identity.blogspot.in/2010/02/tip-interpretation-of-missing-ejb.html) in the comments, I have found out, that the `<NOBODY>` role identifies the deny-all mechanism from JBoss, which is set automatically when no role is specified for an EJB method. This behaviour can be changed in the EJB subsystem configuration by setting (as described in the blog post):

```
<missing-method-permissions-excluded-mode>false</missing-method-permissions-excluded-mode>
```

Comment: changing this worked for me in JBoss 7.2.0.Final <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>

Comment: javatestcase's setting works in JBoss EAP 6.3 as well

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue described above, I set the property "default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access" to "false" in the EJB subsystem (standalone.xml), en detail:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
    ...
    <default-security-domain value="mysecuritydomain"/>
    <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>

</subsystem>
```